# How to destroy myself (the div of dragging by me) when dropped

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

```
$("#b").draggable();
$("#map_canvas").droppable({
drop: function() { 
    //alert('dropped');

    aFn();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#map_canvas").droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) { 
        $(this).remove(); // Destroy droppable
        ui.draggable.remove(); // Destroy draggable
    }
});
```